# Создание горячих клавиш на C# Windows.Forms (примерно как режим рации в Discord)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, hotkeys

Всем доброго времени суток. Столкнулась с проблемой того, что пыталась написать приложение и там есть две функции которые связаны с тем, чтобы пользователь мог юзать горячие клавиши(бинды) для использования некоторого функционала. KeyPreview = true; применяла конечно. Не понимаю почему не получается забиндить комбинации клавиш и клавиши модификаторы по типу Ctrl + G или отдельно Ctrl/Shift etc.
Вот пример того, что у меня получилось, но работает косо криво:

```
    private string bind1;
    private string bind2;
    private InputSimulator inputSimulator = new InputSimulator();

    public RebinderForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += RebinderForm_Load;
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.bindBox.KeyPress += bindBox_KeyPress;
        this.actionBox.KeyPress += actionBox_KeyPress;
    }

    private void RebinderForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void bindBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char keyChar = e.KeyChar;

        if (!char.IsControl(keyChar))
        {
            bindBox.Text = keyChar.ToString();
            bind1 = keyChar.ToString();
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void actionBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char keyChar = e.KeyChar;

        if (!char.IsControl(keyChar))
        {
            actionBox.Text = keyChar.ToString();
            bind2 = keyChar.ToString();
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void ExecuteAction()
    {
        inputSimulator.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(
            WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL,
            WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.VK_A);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создание сочетания клавиш и привязка их в пользовательском интерфейсе.
Для всех форм где используется отлов горячих клавиш устанавливаем
`KeyPreview = true;`
Всё остальное я привязал через конструктор, все события и т.п
Для TextBox(сов) ставим у ReadOnly значение false чтобы запретить ввод пользователю и меняем `BackColor` цвет фона по своему желанию, курсор (Cursor) я установил значением `Hand`

Создаем первую форму где будем проверять комбинации клавиш
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код Form1

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Binding_HotKey_Exemple
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static List<HotKeysArrange> HotKeysLis = new(); //Список со всевозможными комбинациями, сделан статическим чтобы можно было задать его из других форм
        public List<Keys?> KeysListTemp = new(); //Временный список нажатых клавиш, нужен для проверки что было нажато.
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            KeyPreview = true;
        }
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyCode);
            if (!KeysListTemp.Contains(e.KeyCode) && HotKeysLis.Any(hotKey => hotKey.OneKey == e.KeyCode)) //Если первая нажатая клавиша равна первой клавиши любой комбинации, добавляем её
                KeysListTemp.Add(e.KeyCode);

            if (!KeysListTemp.Contains(e.KeyCode) && HotKeysLis.Any(hotKey => hotKey.TwoKey == e.KeyCode)) //Если вторая нажатая клавиша равна второй клавиши любой комбинации, добавляем её
                KeysListTemp.Add(e.KeyCode);

            if (!KeysListTemp.Contains(e.KeyCode) && HotKeysLis.Any(hotKey => hotKey.FreeKey == e.KeyCode)) //Если третья нажатая клавиша равна третьей клавиши любой комбинации, добавляем её
                KeysListTemp.Add(e.KeyCode);

            #region Проверка нажатых клавиш.
            if (KeysListTemp.Count == 1) // Проверяем что в нажатых клавишах для отлова находится одна клавиша
            {
                var temp = HotKeysLis.Where(hotKey => KeysListTemp.Contains(hotKey.OneKey) && hotKey.TwoKey == null && hotKey.FreeKey == null).FirstOrDefault();
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    temp.Action(); //Вызываем наш привязанный метод
                    KeysListTemp.Clear();
                }
            }

            if (KeysListTemp.Count == 2) // Проверяем что в нажатых клавишах для отлова находятся две клавиши
            {
                var temp = HotKeysLis.Where(hotKey => KeysListTemp.Contains(hotKey.OneKey) && KeysListTemp.Contains(hotKey.TwoKey) && hotKey.FreeKey == null).FirstOrDefault();
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    temp.Action();  //Вызываем наш привязанный метод
                    KeysListTemp.Clear();
                }
            }

            if (KeysListTemp.Count == 3) // Проверяем что в нажатых клавишах для отлова находятся три клавиши
            {
                var temp = HotKeysLis.Where(hotKey => KeysListTemp.Contains(hotKey.OneKey) && KeysListTemp.Contains(hotKey.TwoKey) && KeysListTemp.Contains(hotKey.FreeKey)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    temp.Action(); //Вызываем наш привязанный метод
                    KeysListTemp.Clear();
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }

        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) => KeysListTemp.Clear(); //Если пользователь отпустил клавишу, удаляем все данные из списка.

        #region Методы для которых будут задаваться комбинации клавиш
        public void OneMessage() => MessageBox.Show(label1.Text);
        public void TwoMessage() => MessageBox.Show(label2.Text);
        public void FreeMessage() => MessageBox.Show(label3.Text);
        #endregion

        #region Передача методов для привязки их к горячим клавишам
        private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingHotkeyForm form = new(OneMessage, textBox1);
            form.Show();
        }

        private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingHotkeyForm form = new(TwoMessage, textBox2);
            form.Show();
        }

        private void textBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingHotkeyForm form = new(FreeMessage, textBox3);
            form.Show();
        }
        #endregion
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Модель для горячих клавиш, я ограничился тремя сочетаниями комбинаций
    /// </summary>
    public class HotKeysArrange
    {
        public Action Action { get; set; } //Наш метод для привязки к комбинации клавиш
        public Keys? OneKey { get; set; }

        public Keys? TwoKey { get; set; }

        public Keys? FreeKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Создаём вторую форму BindingHotkeyForm
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код BindingHotkeyForm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Binding_HotKey_Exemple
{
    public partial class BindingHotkeyForm : Form
    {
        public Action action;
        HotKeysArrange TempHotKeysArrange = new HotKeysArrange(); //Временная модель для установки горячих клавиш
        private TextBox textBox; //Передаём  textBox из главной формы чтобы отобразить в нем комбинацию клавиш.

        public BindingHotkeyForm(Action action, TextBox textBox)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            KeyPreview = true;
            this.action = action;
            TempHotKeysArrange.Action = action; //Устанавливаем метод который будет работать с заданной комбинацией клавиш
            this.textBox = textBox;
        }
        private void BindingHotkeyForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TempHotKeysArrange.OneKey == null)
            {
                TempHotKeysArrange.OneKey = e.KeyCode;
                textBox1.Text += e.KeyCode.ToString();
                textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
                return;
            }
            if (TempHotKeysArrange.TwoKey == null)
            {
                TempHotKeysArrange.TwoKey = e.KeyCode;
                textBox1.Text += $" + {e.KeyCode}";
                textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
                return;
            }
            if (TempHotKeysArrange.FreeKey == null)
            {
                TempHotKeysArrange.FreeKey = e.KeyCode;
                textBox1.Text += $" + {e.KeyCode}";
                textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0); //Устанавливаем курсор в конец строки, не красиво выглядит когда курсов мигает при каждом изменение в начале....
                return;
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Close(); // В случае отмены закрываем форму

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = $"{(TempHotKeysArrange.OneKey != null ? TempHotKeysArrange.OneKey : "")}" +
                           $"{(TempHotKeysArrange.TwoKey != null ? " + " + TempHotKeysArrange.TwoKey : "")}" +
                           $"{(TempHotKeysArrange.FreeKey != null ? " + " + TempHotKeysArrange.FreeKey : "")}";
            textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0);
            Form1.HotKeysLis.RemoveAll(x => x.Action == action); //Удаляем старые комбинации клавиш для данной привязки
            Form1.HotKeysLis.Add(TempHotKeysArrange); // Добавляем новое сочетание клавиш
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проект можно изучить по ссылке https://github.com/xellans/exemple/tree/main/Binding_HotKey-Exemple

Comment: Спасибо, но я видимо не так выразилась. Я пыталась сделать так, чтобы можно было забиндить любую клавишу или комбинацию клавиш как в режиме рации на примере Дискорда

Comment: @Машкаловитстан хорошо, я обновлю код как закончу пример, и не все люди пользуются дискордом) но я понял что вам нужно

Comment: спасибо большое <3

Comment: @Машкаловитстан обновил ответ, проверяйте)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я попробую <3

Comment: @Машкаловитстан результат я прикрепил, единственное если у вас будут однотипные комбинации например ctrl+alt+c и ctrl+alt+k то код отработает по комбинации которую найдёт первой, увы это так. Нужно писать дополнительные проверки, чтобы было ожидание клавиш если есть схожесть комбинаций. Я могу этим заняться, но не раньше чем через 2-3 дня. Если вы сделаете это раньше, напишите свой ответ в вопросе, если нет. То я займусь этим как освобожусь.

Comment: @Машкаловитстан хотя нет, я ошибся. Сейчас под отладкой проверил ещё раз. ```ctrl+alt+c и ctrl+alt+k ``` такие комбинации работают хорошо.

Comment: Да, хорошо, спасибо)

Comment: А, увидела, поняла

Comment: Странно, но у меня почему-то он не работает, ни в новом проекте, ни в том, что я делаю. Пыталась его лопатить, даже просто копировала(с заменой переменных и т.д. конечно) и всё равно не пашет. Проблема в том, что вторая форма юзает textBox1 как строку и просто записывает туда абсолютно всё. Вы случайно не использовали какие-нибудь библиотеки или что-то ещё?

Comment: @Машкаловитстан исходный проект загрузил на гит https://github.com/xellans/HotKeys-Exemple
```вторая форма юзает textBox1 как строку``` точнее textBox1 выводит только то что вы нажали, он не считывает никаких данных. Нажатые клавиши отлавливаются в Form2_KeyDown и записываются в модель, далее по кнопке сохранить создается в списке комбинация клавиш, которую вы можете проверить у Form1. Конечно для проверки и добавки клавиш формы должны быть в фокусе, так как эти горячие клавиши работают не на уровне системы, а на уровне приложения

Comment: библиотек никаких не использовал, какие то события я задавал в свойствах формы, а не в коде. Это нужно учесть, посмотрите проект. При загрузке формы если какие то события явно не указаны\подписаны в коде, значит их задали  в свойствах, так всегда.  Скорее всего это причина по которой у вас не вышло.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю. Я просто новенькая не разбираюсь совсем :D

Comment: Невероятно. Работает. Я так поняла, вы юзали User Control? Я юзала обычный textBox и у меня отличаются свойства вашего textBox1(Комбинация горячих клавиш) и моего textBox1

Comment: Также у меня не был установлен .NET 6.0 может надо докачать больше всяких приколюшек. Кстати вопрос, знаю, что совсем оборзела: Можно заюзать ваш код в проекте?

Comment: @Машкаловитстан  ```NET 6.0``` я привык уже что давно не использую Net.Framework из за его не актуальности. Вам тоже советую переходить на актуальные средства разработки, быстро почувствуете разницу)  ```Можно заюзать ваш код в проекте?``` Конечно можно, но я решил обновить этот код. Позже обновлю код в вопросе

Comment: @Машкаловитстан ```Я так поняла, вы юзали User Control?``` нет, это есть в wpf,  а у нас проект win form. Возможно что из за того что у вас был Net.Framework что то не доступно было, у того же .net версия языка выше, удобнее писать, что то исправлено в работе и т.п.  ```у меня отличаются свойства вашего textBox1``` я не задавал какие то свойства в коде для элементов, но можно посмотреть отличия в конструкторе, элемент такой же как у вас

Comment: @Машкаловитстан я обновил ответ, проверьте его

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо) А можете порекомендовать средства разработки? Я только вливаюсь и не всё знаю

Comment: @Машкаловитстан я пишу в visual studio как и многие, из советов наверное только могу предложить перейти на net core. Так как Net.Framework использует старую версию языка, но это отличие легче понимать с опытом, так как на этапе обучения без практики базы не получится писать более сложный код, так как его сложнее понимать, именно что он делает. Хорошей практикой для обучения является только те работы цели которых вы выбрали сами и по достижению их вы получаете и теорию и опыт. А получены эти примеры из ответов, исходников и т.п не важно, если вы изучите этот код и поймете как он работает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Тут такой момент, что я не понимаю, где подвязка к текстовой строке данной логики, вообще не понимаю

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да и по-сути действие которое должны выполнять горячие клавиши - это действие другой кнопки. Горячие клавиши - кнопка + кнопка => которые выполняют действие другой комбинации кнопка + кнопка

Comment: @Машкаловитстан Когда человека нет в дискуссии (не написал ни единого комментария под постом), он не получит уведомление, как-бы вы ни писали его ник. Уведомление человек получает только тогда, когда вам позволяет через @ указать его ник (например, под моим ответом). В итоге я спустя 10 часов чудом увидел, что вы мне что-то написали... Теперь про сам вопрос - если он адресован мне, то почему он под этим ответом? Я не его автор и не я за него отвечаю.

Comment: @Машкаловитстан А так, я вам уже сказал как делать, словарь с действиями, что-то по типу `Dictionary<string, Action>` через который даете уникальное название команде, а при биндинге клавиш, указываете не `Action`, а ключ этого словаря, дале просто меняете сопоставление команды, вместо вызова сразу `command.Action?.Invoke()` делаете сначала поиск `dictionary[command.ActionKey].Invoke()`, все. Но повторю, я не отвечаю за код, что выше, вы определитесь, какой именно код вы берете на вооружение, его автора и спрашивайте как сделать...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да кстати, спасибо вам большое, я смогла сделать без доп. окон сразу в окне формы биндов и не настолько короткий и красивый код как ваш, но получилось, я как допилю, выложу) Спасибо вам ещё раз за совет)

Answer (score 3):

Что-то в ответе ранее куча лишнего и довольно костыльного, когда все это сводится к нескольким строкам кода. Частично это дубликат ответа (ну а как без них, основано все на одном ведь) от xellan, но вместо написания кучи комментариев думаю, а дай напишу по своему)

- Для начала давайте сделаем класс, который будет иметь в себе название и действие кнопки. Так, как действие у нас нечто абстрактное, то мы смело можем брать `Action`. В итоге получаем к примеру такое:

  ```
  public record HotKeyInfo(string Name, Action? Action);
  ```
- Далее нам нужно место, где мы будем хранить все наши хоткеи. Обычно на одну горячую клавишу вешается один обработчик, а это значит, что нам отлично подойдет `Dictionary`, ключом которого будет служить стандартный `Keys`, который является простым `Enum`, да еще и помечем как флаг, что позволяет делать битовые операции. В итоге получаем такое:

  ```
  public Dictionary<Keys, HotKeyInfo> HotKeys { get; private set; } = [];
  ```
- Дальше нам нужно получить текущие нажатые клавиши формы, а именно событие `OnKeyDown`. Пишем в классе формы `override`, жмем пробел и выбираем из предложенного списка `OnKeyDown`, готово, у нас появился такой код, где в `e.KeyData` будут наши кнопки:

  ```
  protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      base.OnKeyDown(e);
  }
  ```
- Теперь наша цель взять из словаря описание хоткея (в случае наличия такого там) и вызвать его `Action`. Делается это элементарно:

  ```
  protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      base.OnKeyDown(e);

      if (HotKeys.TryGetValue(e.KeyData, out var hotKeyInfo))
      {
          hotKeyInfo.Action?.Invoke();
      }
  }
  ```
- Поздравляю, осталось лишь заполнить словарь данными. Например, напишем такое в конструкторе окна:

  ```
  HotKeys.Add(Keys.Control | Keys.A, new("Тестовая команда 1", ()=> { Debug.WriteLine($"Мы нажали { Name }"); }));
  HotKeys.Add(Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.D, new("Тестовая команда 2", ()=> { Debug.WriteLine("Мм, а это команда 2"); }));
  ```
- Запускаем, жмем клавиши и видим как в окне отладки появляется то, что мы указали.

  [image: Result]

Собственно вот вам универсальный и довольно простой способ сделать команды в вашем приложении. Дальше уже подключайте фантазию, развивайте эту идею как хотите. Хотите делать интерфейс, пожалуйста, сохраните последнее сочетание клавиш все через тот-же `OnKeyDown` и сделайте `HotKeys.TryAdd(e.KeyData, ...);`. Хотите добавить описание, вперед, редактируйте `HotKeyInfo` под себя и используйте где надо. Ну и так далее.

И да, я надеюсь вы поняли, что `Action` это условно говоря метод, то есть вы можете там указать лямбду как я`()=> что-то;`, а можете создать отдельный метод `void` и уже прописать там просто его имя (`.Add(..., new("Команда", OnHotKey1Pressed));`). Ну и также вы можете это все кастомизировать под свои нужды, передавая параметры если надо, получая может быть какие либо данные, ну и др.

В общем, вот вам самый простейший пример, изучайте, дорабатывайте, пробуйте. Удачи!

---

Весь код:

```
public record HotKeyInfo(string Name, Action? Action);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Dictionary<Keys, HotKeyInfo> HotKeys { get; private set; } = [];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HotKeys.Add(Keys.Control | Keys.A, new("Тестовая команда 1", ()=> { Debug.WriteLine($"Мы нажали { Name }"); }));
        HotKeys.Add(Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.D, new("Тестовая команда 2", ()=> { Debug.WriteLine("Мм, а это команда 2"); }));
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        if (HotKeys.TryGetValue(e.KeyData, out var hotKeyInfo))
        {
            hotKeyInfo.Action?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Замечания в комментариях показали некий недостаток кода, а именно то, что использование `KeyData` не очень надежно, ибо при некоторых сочетаниях оно дает одно и тоже значение, игнорируя некоторые клавиши. По этой причине, лучше писать свою реализацию, сохраняя клавиши поочередно в коллекцию. Тогда код измениться на нечто такое:

```
public record HotKeyInfo(string Name, Action? Action);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Dictionary<int, HotKeyInfo> HotKeys { get; private set; } = [];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HotKeys.Add(ToKeyValues(Keys.ControlKey, Keys.A), new("Тестовая команда 1", ()=> { Debug.WriteLine($"Мы нажали { Name }"); }));
        HotKeys.Add(ToKeyValues(Keys.ShiftKey, Keys.D, Keys.F), new("Тестовая команда 2", ()=> { Debug.WriteLine("Мм, а это команда 2"); }));
    }

    private int ToKeyValues(params Keys[] keys) 
        => keys.Sum(x => (int)x);


    private HashSet<Keys> _pressedKeys = [];
    private HashSet<Keys> _allKeys = [];
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _allKeys.Add(e.KeyCode);
        _pressedKeys.Add(e.KeyCode);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _allKeys.Remove(e.KeyCode);

        if (_allKeys.Count == 0)
        {
            var hotKeyCode = ToKeyValues([.. _pressedKeys]);

            if (HotKeys.TryGetValue(hotKeyCode, out var hotKeyInfo))
            {
                hotKeyInfo.Action?.Invoke();
            }

            _pressedKeys.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Поясняю:

- Словарь теперь хранит числовое значение кнопок, их сумму. Если мы зайдем [в документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys), то увидим, что к примеру клавиша `Ctrl` будет иметь код `17`, а допустим `A` будет иметь `65`, их сочетание будет 17+65 = `82`, это и будет уникальный код нашей комбинации. Такая реализация позволит нажимать клавиши в любой последовательности, да и с любым кол-вом клавиш.
- `ToKeyValues` - это вспомогательный метод, который и суммирует код клавиш, отдавая результат.
- `HashSet<Keys> _pressedKeys` и `HashSet<Keys> _allKeys` - Так, как клавиша не может быть нажата дважды, нам нужна коллекция, которая хранит в себе только уникальные значения, ну а это именно `HashSet`. В `_pressedKeys` мы будем хранить все нажатые кнопки пользователем до тех пор, пока нажата хоть одна клавиша, в конце это и будет нужное сочетание клавиш. Ну а `_allKeys` будет неким индикатором, что нажато в данный момент, мы в нее будем добавлять при нажатии и сразу удалять из нее при отжатии клавиши.
- `OnKeyDown` - Переопределяем событие, которое происходит в момент зажатия клавиши. В нем мы добавляем нажатую кнопку в наши коллекции.
- `OnKeyUp` - Обратное `OnKeyDown`, выполняется в момент отжатия клавиши. В нем мы удаляем клавишу из `_allKeys`, и если эта коллекция пуста (все клавиши отжаты) начинаем сверять комбинацию клавиш с нашим списком.
- Ну а остальное, думаю и так понятно, ибо описывал выше. Мы формируем код нашей комбинации клавиш, ищем его в словаре, если есть такой, то вызываем, ну а если нету, проходим мимо.

Собственно, теперь думаю все проблемы тут решены. Код остался вроде такой-же простой и понятный, без каких либо дубликатов и хардкора на три клавиши) Есть правда одно НО, мы потеряли возможность зажимать комбинацию клавиш, ибо триггер срабатывания у нас "если все клавиши отжаты". Так что, если вам нужно именно "зажимать", то код нужно будет немного переделать, а именно в момент зажатия клавиши подсчитывать код комбинации, искать если есть и выполнять пока клавиша зажата, но это уже пусть будет в виде домашнего задания.

Comment: хороший ответ, но например в вашем примере не будет работать cntrl + a + c и т.п, ваш пример ограничен тем что нельзя выбрать произвольные комбинации.  для этого придётся реализовать коллекции для хранения нажатий, и т.п, и придётся сделать кучу if как у меня в примере, так как есть условия при которых эти варианты работают не правильно. Поэтому не думаю что код можно написать короче, но можно сделать только красивее архитектуру.

Comment: @xellan Почему не будет работать? Все должно без проблем работать. Единственное, будет вызываться еще и первая команда, ибо она на `Ctrl+A` привязана, но это решается довольно просто - небольшой задержкой и ее прерыванием если нажата другая команда, после чего вызывается последняя введенная. И не надо никаких `if`, которые зачем-то используете вы, дублируя кучу кода.

Comment: ```HotKeys.Add(Keys.Shift | Keys.D | Keys.F, new("Тестовая команда 2", () => { Debug.WriteLine("Мм, а это команда 2"); }));```
Срабатывает при нажатии Shift + F
```Keys.Menu | Keys.F``` не работает вообще. Можно найти и другие комбинации которые не будут работать. Так как Keys или modifierkeys жестко привязаны к командным клавишам и вариантов их использования не так много. Перед тем как обновить код в ответе, у меня был такой же пример как у вас, но он сильно ограничивает комбинации.

Comment: ```Keys.Control | Keys.S | Keys.W``` срабатывает по нажатию ctrl+w да таких вариантов много, это проблема с точки зрения что пользователь может использовать комбинацию ctrl+w и ctrl+s+w

Comment: ```решается довольно просто - небольшой задержкой и ее прерыванием если нажата другая команда, после чего вызывается последняя введенная.``` пока зажата какая то клавиши то ```OnKeyDown``` работает зациклено, не правильно если указать включение задержки, то она станет зацикленной. Лучше проверять что нажато в возможных комбинациях и исходя из этого выбирать нужную. Мне кажется вариант с задержкой не подходящим к ситуации. Да и если пользователь будет нажимать последнюю клавиши дольше чем время задержки, что будет не известно.

Comment: @xellan Да, странно себя ведет `KeyData`, не заметил этого сразу. Хорошо, доработал тогда код с использованием коллекций.

Comment: можете исправить ответ что мой код плохой пример для реализации)

Comment: @xellan Согласен, немного неудачный код у вас получился, ибо он у вас состоит почему-то из дублирования кода, их странных реализаций по типу `if (!KeysListTemp.Contains(e.KeyCode) && HotKeysLis.Any(hotKey => hotKey.OneKey == e.KeyCode))`, а также вы там не написали что всякие эти методы надо привязывать к UI контролам, из-за чего человек (новичок) как я понял не смог запустить изначально. Также статика (очень спорное решение), ну и также передача целого `TextBox` в другую форму - это прям отвратное решение. Но говорить прям "плохой пример для реализации" я не могу.

Comment: @xellan Моя задача была лишь показать как можно повторить тот-же почти функционал, но без кучи дублирования и лишних проверок. С задачей я думаю справился, наверно и вы с него подчерпнули что-то полезное. Ну а судить какой код лучше, за автора вопроса, я не могу, это неправильно)

Comment: ```из-за чего человек (новичок) как я понял не смог запустить изначально.``` у автора не вышло, так как не были привязаны события к форме, я подметил это сразу дав ответ.  И об не привязки событий, я не думал, для этого обсуждения и есть, чтобы решать вопросы)
```он у вас состоит почему-то из дублирования кода``` универсальный метод для решения задачи врятли получится, если можно укоротить этот код сохранив логическую часть, это было бы для меня новым опытом)

Comment: ```Моя задача была лишь показать как можно повторить тот-же почти функционал, но без кучи дублирования и лишних проверок``` я ответил в комментариях почему это не работает, и у меня был такой же пример изначально) Потом пришлось придумывать решение, кода была мало, но позже при тестах стали появляться все эти условия)

Comment: @xellan Простите, не работает что? Что сейчас допустим не так в моем коде, ради чего стоило бы писать так, как у вас в вопросе? Мне кажется, мой пример весьма универсальный и покрывает почти все потребности, остается только вынести в отдельный класс, состряпать  UI и команды, все.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1562510/Создание-горячих-клавиш-на-c-windows-forms-примерно-как-режим-рации-в-discord/1562845?noredirect=1#comment2815349_1562845 писал выше

Comment: @xellan Так обновленный код лишен этих недостатков, разве нет?

Comment: новый код явно решают эту проблему если его переписать на работу с зажатыми клавишами. Но ссылаясь на реализацию, есть один минус, сумма случайно может совпадать с суммой других комбинаций. Вероятность маленькая, но если посчитать коды клавиш между собой, то сумма может совпадать.

Comment: @xellan в теории может, да, и если такое будет происходить, решить подобное довольно просто, хоть сохранением хэшей, хоть созданием отдельного списка. Делать это не стал ибо шанс повторения невелик, особенно для трехзначных команд, ну а нагружать ответ лишним, ну такое...